# Is there a chess position equivalent to the Collatz conjecture?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory, lo.logic, chess

Suppose we have an infinite board with a finite number of chess pieces. The question is whether white can checkmate black (without the after 50 moves it is a draw rule). Can you give an explicit position of which you can prove that white can checkmate black if and only if the [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) is true?

This problem is motivated by the fact that for my answer to the question [Decidability of chess on an infinite board](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27967/decidability-of-chess-on-an-infinite-board) I did not get any votes. I strongly believe that chess is undecidable but the proof seems to involve a lot of designing of chess positions. That is why I thought this problem would be a good warm up as the Collatz conjecture seems to be easily realizable with a "chess automaton".

First, one should design a position for every number n that can check the parity, divide by 2 or go to 3n+1. I guess this should not be that hard. Then one should devise a mechanism that lets black choose this original number n, maybe something like suggested here [Checkmate in $\omega$ moves?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63423/checkmate-in-omega-moves/63517#63517).

If you think this question is not for mathoverflow, please suggest some other forum.

Comment: Don't you have to be careful with question like this to be quite precise? At the minute can't I just say "the answer is yes because Collatz is either true or false and in either case such a position exists"?

Comment: PS see Carl Mummert's answer to the first question you link to, and subsequent comments, for more evidence that, without a completely rigorous specification of what you're after, the question is ambiguous (and perhaps even subjective and argumentative!)

Comment: I re-edited the question, although I can think it should be pretty clear what I mean. Also, imo Carl Mummert's answer is a complete misinterpretation of what input means, as pointed out in the first comment to that answer by Joel David Hamkins.

Comment: Note: domotorp has edited the question now and my first comment (made about a previous version) is no longer valid :-/

Comment: I want to mention that in its original form, the Collatz conjecture is not a Halting problem (although someone might have found it equivalent to a Halting problem, I don't know). The Collatz conjecture is a \(\Pi^0_2\) question. So, even if halting problems can be expressed as chess problems on an infinite board, it doesn't mean that Collatz conjecture can be expressed as it. So, this question seems to be more complicated than 27967. 

Comment: Really, why can it not be formulated as a halting problem? Take a Turing machine that on input n, divides by 2 if n is even and outputs 3n+1, if n is odd, and keeps repeating this until it reaches 1. To decide whether this machine stops is a halting problem. Also, in a more complicated way, I think any mathematical statement can be formulated as whether a Turing-machine halts - just take one that tries to enumerate all possible proofs and check if one of them is correct.

Comment: Lucas K.: yes, but have you seen question 63517 which asks about positions that are potentially even harder to compute.  

Comment: domotorp, for a particular n, it is a halting problem, but the Collatz conjecture is for any n. Enumerating the proofs only works with completeness. And we know that logics are not complete.

Comment: Ok, I finally see what you mean. You are right that in this way we could even express a logically more complicated statement but as Ambrus points out, there is a good chance that it is doable. Then a question for logicians: Is there a question that cannot be expressed by a chess position? Maybe a formal way of asking this would be: Is there a poly time algorithm that transforms any statement to an equivalent chess position with a finite number of pieces?

Comment: No cycle in the Collatz conjecture leads on to new integers not in the cycle.  Chess however can admit a cycle of the same positions, subsequently leading on to new positions not in the cycle. Therefore I don't think any position of chess pieces that will subsequently admit an exitable cycle can be mapped to the Collatz conjecture.

But it's clear that every chess position inevitably leads to a potential cycle unless a pawn move is guaranteed.  Therefore any chess position equivalent to the Collatz Conjecture contains only board states in which a pawn move is always inevitable.

Comment: @Robert: I disagree. For example, suppose that a piece has to stay at the origin, while the other pieces can (after a sequence of moves) all go one higher, or one to the right etc.

Comment: @domotorp but a defence by black can include a cycle and the collatz function can't describe that.

Comment: @Robert: If the position is constructed appropriately (and I believe it can be), then there won't be a cycle.

Comment: @domotorp I agree that may be possible.  I'm just commenting on one condition that's necessary to 'construct appropriately'.  You will have to be in such a position that black is unable to defend with a cycle.  This may mean some irreversible move is inevitable such as taking a piece or moving a pawn. I was wrong earlier that moving a pawn is the only irreversible move.

Comment: See also: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8582/can-chess-simulate-a-universal-turing-machine