# How many solutions of x^3 +y^3 = z^3+3 are known?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, open-problems

I've been told that there is reason to think that the equation

$x^3 + y^3 = z^3 + 3$ has solutions in positive integers other than

$$4^3 + 4^3 = 5^3 +3.$$

Can someone tell me the current status of this problem?  Is there another solution known?

Here's a reference to the problem in greater generality.

MATHEMATICS OF COMPUTATION
Volume 66, Number 218, April 1997, Pages 841–851
S 0025-5718(97)00830-2
ON SEARCHING FOR SOLUTIONS OF
THE DIOPHANTINE EQUATION $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = n$

Comment: In https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.04284 it is shown that there are no other with $|x|,|y|,|z|<10^{16}$.

Comment: Could mention that https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58188/are-nontrivial-integer-solutions-known-for-x3y3z3-3?rq=1 has an extensive discussion, as of 2011, of a possibly easier yet still seemingly infeasible problem.

Comment: Another solution to $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 3$ in integers is now known (Sept.2019): $569936821221962380720^3 + (-569936821113563493509)^3 + (-472715493453327032)^3 = 3$. This does not rearrange to $a^3 + b^3 = c^3 + 3$ in *positive* integers $a, b, c$.